Composition with adjunction is an adjunction
Say I have adjoints $E\dashv W\dashv A$.
Then is it the case that $E\circ W\dashv A\circ W$ ?
If so, why, and can we generalize it?

Yes, and also $W \circ E \vdash W \circ A$. The proof is easy enough if you think in terms of $\mathrm{Hom}$-isomorphisms.

@NaïmFavier I see! It's trivial with homs indeed. Thanks!
